# add column to select object zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-framework3, zend-db-select

Here is my current code:

```
$Select=new Select();
$Select->from($this->getTable());
```

What I want now is to add the `id column` but as `DT_RowId` instead of `id`. How do I accomplish this? The goal would be to have all of the table columns as well as this new column.

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the rest of your table definition? preferably one of your current situation and one of the desired situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need both "old" and "new" fields, don't forget to add an asterisk.

```
$Select=new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
$Select->from($this->getTable());
$Select->columns([
  '*', 
  'DT_RowId' => 'id',
  'furtherColumn' => 'furtherColumn'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest soloution would be to use the columns function with an associative array with aliases as the keys for example:

```
$select=new Select();
$select->from($this->getTable());
$select->columns(array(
 'DT_RowId' => 'id',
 'furtherColumn' => 'furtherColumn',
));
```